# Changing Microsoft Outlook Default OneNote Application

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-onenote

Issue: Clicking OneNote Ribbon item in Outlook uses OneNote 2016 Desktop Application.

Desired Outcome: I want it to send to Window's 10 OneNote and populate those notebooks/sections.

For arbitrary reasons, I have both OneNote versions installed, mostly for local and old notebooks.

I've tried changing the default version by following [this tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-default-version-of-onenote-on-your-computer-f261140c-5ce8-4cf4-ad0b-c9e1cb953831) with no progress.

My Windows 10 OneNote version defaults:
[image]

My OneNote 2016 version defaults:
[image]

I do not have the option to alter the remaining protocols. These are the options that populate for those remaining protocols:

[image]

---

Versions:

Microsoft Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.9330.2073) 32-bit

Comment: I'm guessing this is because this button does not use the system filetype handlers, but instead uses one of the internal Office communication methods. It's not creating or opening a file, it's talking directly to OneNote 2016, allowing richer and therefore more capable communication.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, since they are installed from the same Suite. Still doesn't sound practical in that Microsoft themselves are recommending the OneNote Win 10 version. I suppose I'll use the [EmailToOneNote](https://www.onenote.com/EmailToOneNote) method until Microsoft Office 2019 comes out or a work around is offered. Thanks @music2myear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office applications have used DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange) for a while for most inter-MSOffice communication. It is unlikely this will change in a future version.

DDE enables many of the advanced cross-application functionality within Office, and I don't believe system protocol handlers even begin to be capable of the functions DDE offers.

Assuming you're dealing with the "Send to OneNote" button in Outlook or other Office products, this is not looking for the handler for the various OneNote file types. Instead, it is packaging the data from the source content and then sending this data to OneNote directly, no need to check for protocol or file handler settings.

In fact, the Send to OneNote button in Office products cannot be reprogrammed either. It is a plugin, applied BY the installation of OneNote for Office. Uninstall OneNote from your Office install, and this plugin and button goes away.

To put it bluntly: The Send to OneNote button in Office products will only EVER send to the Office version of OneNote.

This means that your solution is to create a new button. It should be rather simple, actually. You just need a button that triggers a print job and sends to the Print To OneNote function, and then make sure the app version of OneNote is the default OneNote application.

Comment: So, with your workaround, I found that I needed to install another application '[Send to OneNote](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/send-to-onenote/9mvjm1z9vwjd)', this might be circumstantial, simply FYI for future readers.